# lighttpd mod_compress not compressing application/json type

Tags: json, flask, lighttpd

Has anyone else encountered the following?  I'm trying to use lighttpd, running the FastCGI/flup server and the Flask framework, to serve a JSON-based RESTful API.

I'm using Flask's RESTful extension package, which marshals Python data into a JSON object to be returned as a string.  This works fine... "Content-Type: application/json" is placed in the response header and the JSON string is in the response.

What I'd like to do is compress the returned JSON if the client indicates it will accept it.  I have mod_compress enabled in lighttpd.conf, with the following directive indicating the MIME types to compress:

```
compress.filetype = ( "application/json", "text/json", "text/javascript",
"application/x-javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )
```

The client (browser-based) is always sending an "Accept-Type: gzip, ..." header.  When lighttpd returns "text/*" MIME types, it is setting the "Content-Encoding: gzip" header and compressing the data fine, and the client handles it fine.

However, this is not working for the "application/json" MIME type, and I'm scratching my head.  Even though the API goes through the Flask path, isn't lighttpd responsible for setting the "Content-Encoding: gzip" header and compressing the data for the "application/json" MIME type as well?

Comment: Found the answer. The lighttpd docs for mod_compress say lighttpd will only compress static files; therefore if I want to compress my API output I will need to find a way to do it on the fly (in my case, via the Flask RESTful API).  hope this information is helpful to someone.

Comment: mod_deflate claims to be able to compress dynamic content, though it doesn't create a cache (which most people don't want anyway). https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModDeflate